# How to reshape my input to feed it into 1D Convolutional layer for sequence classification?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have a csv file with 339732 rows and two columns :

- the first being 29 feature values, i.e. X
- the second being a binary label value, i.e. Y

  dataframe = pd.read_csv("features.csv", header = None)
          dataset = dataframe.values

  ```
  X = dataset[:, 0:29].astype(float)
  Y = dataset[:,29]
  X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, random_state = 42)
  ```

I am trying to train it on a 1D convolutional layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[0], 29)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=2)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=16)
```

Since, the Conv1D layer expects a 3-D input, I transformed my input as follows:

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (1, X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (1, X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1]))
```

However, this still throws error:

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv1d_1/convolution/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,29], [1,3,29,64].

Is there any way to feed my input correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know 1D Convolution layer accepts inputs of the form Batchsize x Width x Channels. You are reshaping with

`X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (1, X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]))`

But `X_train.shape[0]` is your **batchsize** I guess.I think the problem is somewhere here. Can you please tell what is the shape of X_train before reshape?

Comment: Before reshape, X_train's shape is (339732, 29). Also, what could be the possible value for channels in case of sequences? (Doesn't that make sense just for images?)

Comment: Ok, so what you are trying to do is feed a vector of length 29 to CNN. 339732 such vectors are there. You can imagine each of them as an image with height 1, width 29 and channels 1. CNN2D input shape will be (1,29,1) as (rows,cols,channels). CNN1D input shape should be (29,1). Please reshape your X_Train as (339732 x 29 x 1) for CNN1D, if you are using CNN2D then reshape as (339732 x 1 x 29 x 1). That should work.

Comment: Did it, gives the error: `ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (None, 339732, 29) but got array with shape (339732, 29, 1)`

Comment: My bad. Adjusting the input_shape to `(29,1)` just did the work!

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about if your data have some progression relation between the 339732 entries or the 29 features, this means if the order matters. If not I don't think that CNN is suitable for this case.

If the 29 features "indicates the progression of something":

> X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1],1))

If the 29 features are independent, then is like the channels on the image, but doesn't make sense convolute with only 1.

> X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],1, X_train.shape[1]))

If you want to pick the 339732 entries like in blocks where the order matters (clip the 339732 or add zero padding in order to be divisible by timesteps):

> X_train = X_train.reshape((int(X_train.shape[0]/timesteps),timesteps, X_train.shape[1],1))